# Does var directory in the linux file system hierarchy has any performance implications?

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel

I've been reading the purpose of top level directories in the linux file system hierarchy and it's suggested `/var` be used for variable data.

(Ref: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/var.html)

My question is:
Since it is used mainly for writeable data, are there any performance implications?

For example:

1. all the writes to files under `/var` has a separate page cache pooling and page eviction strategy as it is mostly sequential io or
2. just one kernel thread to flush any data written under this hierarchy as performance is not of highest need?

Or is it simply a mounting convenience without any performance implications?

Comment: it is neither. The perf. impl. comes when you mount a "special" disk on /var. The convenience comes from systemd etc. using this /var for permanent writes. (where /tmp would not do, and /usr/... is "unsatisfactory")